# #1052 - column id in where clause is ambigious

Tags: mysql, sql

I’m trying to join three tables and don’t know why this message keeps coming up. Below is my SQL:

```
select*
FROM payment,customer,purchase
where cname = 'Ben Parker', AND cid = '21' AND pid = '12';
```

Comment: `JOIN`, `JOIN`, `JOIN`!!!

Comment: ive tried that cant seem to do it how would i structure it as a query

Comment: What is the structure of the three tables? Please [edit] your answer to add that information.

Comment: If more than one of the tables has columns with the same name, then the query *is* ambiguous. Which `payid` column did you mean? That explains the error message. It’s not an answer in itself, but others have answered it adequately.

Comment: If you [edit] your question to include the structure of the three tables, I might try my hand at an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use JOINS instead of the where clause
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

```
select*
FROM payment p
JOIN customer c
ON c.cusid = p.cusid   --assuming cusid is present in both the tables
JOIn purchase pu
ON pu.payid = p.payid   --assuming payid is present in both the tables
where c.cusname = 'Ben Parker' AND c.cusid = '21' AND p.payid = '12';
```

And if you still want it your way then this is the way(not recommended)

```
select*
FROM payment p,customer c,purchase pu
where c.cusname = 'Ben Parker' AND c.cusid = '21' AND p.payid = '12';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write `tablename.columnname = '....'`

Comment: For example payid is coming from payment table..then write payment.payid = '12'